# Connect to Openfire server via Android

Tags: java, android, xmpp, openfire

I'm trying to connect to my running Openfire server with this code:

```
public static final String HOST = "ipofmyserver";
public static final int PORT = 9122;  // set by me
//public static final String SERVICE = "gmail.com"; not used because i don't know what it refers to

ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration(HOST, PORT);
XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Connect to the server
    try {
        connection.connect();
    } catch (XMPPException e) {
        connection = null;
        //Unable to connect to server
    }

    //Most servers require you to login before performing other tasks.
    if (connection != null) {
        try {
            connection.login("xxxx", "xxxx");
        } catch (XMPPException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**LOGCAT**

http://pastebin.com/9fcbzqgj

**EDIT**

i added an exceptionininitializer exception and now it doesn't crash, but now i get a:

```
05-07 03:27:55.734    3184-3184/xxx.xxx.xxxxxE/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext', referenced from method org.jivesoftware.smack.util.dns.JavaxResolver.<clinit>
```

**UPDATE**

i've read that Android only allows access to some of the standard JRE classes, which are in this whitelist https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist

so.. what should i do if i want to use the Smack api? I can't? I tried with aSmack, but it has to be compiled on linux or mac, and i only got windows

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement XMPP chat in an android app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23507724/how-to-implement-xmpp-chat-in-an-android-app)

Answer (score 0):

Please if you are using the smack api then along with this api you must also use the xpp.jar into your project. I also faced up the same issue and solved this problem with this api.

here is the link for that api. [Xpp download link](http://www.extreme.indiana.edu/dist/java-repository/xpp3/distributions/xpp3-1.1.3.4.C_all.tgz)

Answer (score 0):

In Android studio gradle, dependencies working for me:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android:4.1.1'
  compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android-extensions:4.1.1'
  compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-core:4.1.1'
  compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.1.1'
  compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-extensions:4.1.1'
  compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-experimental:4.1.1'
  compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-resolver-minidns:4.1.1'
  compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-sasl-provided:4.1.1'
  compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-im:4.1.1'
  compile 'org.jxmpp:jxmpp-core:0.4.2-beta1'
  compile 'org.jxmpp:jxmpp-util-cache:0.4.2-beta1'
  compile 'de.measite.minidns:minidns:0.1.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
}
```