# How to implement XMPP chat in an android app?

Tags: java, android, xmpp, openfire, smack

I tried using the Smack library, but all i get is this:

```
05-07 04:28:43.299    2958-2958/g.d.allinonechat E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext', referenced from method org.jivesoftware.smack.util.dns.JavaxResolver.<clinit>
```

that with a search on Google i found out, Google doesn't let some JRE classes work on Android, so.. nothing to do here

tried aSmack, i'm using windows, tried compiling it on Linux Ubuntu, but it wouldn't compile

```
./build.bash line 142 /root/Desktop/asmack-master/version-tags/4.0.0-rc2-SNAPSHOT-2014-04-27.tag: No such file or directory
```

the file doesn't exist, but i tried downloading the zipped file twice, and it isn't there nor it is dynamically generated.

Is there any other library i could use to connect to my Openfire server?

Thank You.

Comment: place your asmack library in libs folder and clean your project and then try.

Comment: i tried that, but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your own build of aSmack; I had exactly the same problem with the build script.

I discovered that directories `releases` and `version-tags` were missing. In your configuration I suggest to execute:

```bsh
mkdir -p /root/Desktop/asmack-master/version-tags/
mkdir -p /root/Desktop/asmack-master/releases/
cd /root/Desktop/asmack-master/build.bash
./build.bash
```

Also do not forget to create `local.properties` file for `ant` in order to build final `jar`.

```bsh
cp /root/Desktop/asmack-master/local.properties{.example,}
```

It is needed to set path to the Android-SDK in the `local.properties`. In my environment it looks like this:

```
sdk-location=${user.home}/android-sdk-linux/
```

Then you can find final `jar`s in `releases` directory.

Another alternative is to use already pre-built `jar`s of aSmack http://asmack.freakempire.de/ as [aSmack GitHub page suggests](https://github.com/flowdalic/asmack).

Edit: Problem with non-existing directories has been just fixed in the aSmack project. Build script will create them in case they are missing.